# What happened to the hrplimittablerelationship table in ax-2012-r2?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Any advice on how I can replace the following code from AX 2009?

```
display amount mrpg_limit()
{
     return HRPLimitTableRelationship::find("Spending", emplTable_1.PartyId).LimitValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HRPLimittableRelationship table was moved to multiple tables

- HRPApprovedLimit
- HRPApprovedLimitAmount

If you want more details about the process of how this was changed, look at the data upgrade scripts on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj737032.aspx

This TechNet article describes the actual creation of signing limits, in case you need it for testing.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh271654.aspx

Taking a shot in the dark on getting the information you wanted, there is a class called **PurchReqDocument** with a static method of **spendingLimitStatic**, where you supply the worker recid and currency code.